# Report on all function hierarchies calling a given function in Perl

Tags: perl

Given a function name, I would like to report the call hierarchy 'all the way to the top'.

For example,

```
# ./find.pl functionName
functionName
caller
    caller2
    ...
        callerN
```

In the above output, I learn that callerN is the 'top level' function that ends up calling the 'lowest level' functionName function.

I've been trying to accomplish this but the implementation always has flaws. It's not reliable enough for me to have confidence in it.

Is there something that will do this already?

Thank you

Comment: You can't have reliable. e.g. `$o->foo`. e.g. `sub f { my $name = shift; my $ref = \&$name; $ref->(@_); }`.

Comment: I knew about that, but for a majority of our cases it's simple symbol imports and calls. Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: So you want a call stack of a given function without actually calling it?

Comment: Yes, basically I want to report all the areas of the code that use a given function so that I can judge what areas are impacted by changes to 'shared' code.

Answer (score 3):

[NYTProf](http://search.cpan.org/~timb/Devel-NYTProf-4.09/lib/Devel/NYTProf.pm) is a debugging package that allows very fine-grained inspection of function calls. It can output to HTML to see a detailed (runtime) profile. For your requirements it might be helpful to see the call graphs that it can output as well.

Example code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

&say_hi;

sub say_hi {
    print &hello;
}
sub hello {
    return "Hello world!\n";
}
```

Called with:

```
$ perl -d:NYTProf hello.pl
```

Produces a file called `nytprof.out` in the current dir, which `nytprof` can parse:

```
$ nytprof nytprof.out --open
```

This will create a dir called `nytprof` and automatically open a browser on the profiling result page for you. The interesting part may be the graphs that you can download (but they are located in the `nytprof` dir as well). These call graphs are organized in levels that might provide insights into what parts of your program call what functions. The call graph for this simple program looks like this:

[image: Call graph for simple hello world program]

PS: The graphs are provided as dot files. To create a SVG from `graph.dot`, say

```
$ dot -Tsvg -o graph.svg graph.dot
```

More in the `dot` manual.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I love nytprof but it would have to run the code and I can't hit all the cases as it's a web app with a lot of functionality

Answer (score 1):

If actually running the code is feasible, you can use the caller() function, or the encapsulated version [Devel::Stacktrace](http://search.cpan.org/~drolsky/Devel-StackTrace-1.30/lib/Devel/StackTrace.pm).

If you depend on code analysis ... [Lscharf's combination of PPI and GraphViz](http://www.teragridforum.org/mediawiki/index.php?title=Perl_Static_Source_Code_Analysis#Perl_Subroutine_Call_Tree) might be of use. No idea whether it is current, though, or whether it catches any of the myriad of edge cases, such as mentioned by ikegami above.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, unfortunately running the code to hit every case isn't feasible.

Comment: But, PPI does look interesting!

Answer (score 1):

You could `use Carp` and its `cluck` function, which prints the call stack. See their [documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/Carp.html) for more information.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Carp qw(cluck);

&subsub;

sub callstack {
    cluck "waaah";
}

sub subsub {
    &callstack;
}
```

Output:

```
$ perl /tmp/test.pl
waaah at /tmp/test.pl line 10
    main::callstack called at /tmp/test.pl line 14
    main::subsub called at /tmp/test.pl line 7
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, unfortunately running the code to hit every case isn't feasible.

Comment: @DaleForester: I don't understand. What do you mean by "running the code to hit every case"?

Comment: I mean it's a web app with multiple ways to access it and use its varied functionality. Using cluck I would have to hit every functionality to get that kind of report. I need something automated that can tell me the locations that end up using low level function.

Comment: @DaleForester: I see. I added another answer, maybe that is more helpful?